# "Unexpected character after line continuation character" when running .py file?

Tags: python

I'm brand new to Python, so excuse my ignorance. I also checked the other questions with this same error, but they all regarded the escape sequence "\n". When attempting to run a python file from my Documents in the Python command line, I get the error "unexpected character after line continuation character."

I've tried reading straight from *W3Schools*, which says to use...

`C:\Users\Your Name>python helloworld.py`

Since my file is in Documents in a file called `test`, I tried...

`C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>python test.py`

However, I received the given error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

***Edit***

In the OS command prompt, the `py` prefix should have been used, rather than `python`

Comment: Could you post here what your `test.py` file looks like? If you try with a completely empty `test.py` do you still get the error?

Comment: Possible reason: Somewhere in your code you have a line that seems to have a trailing backslash (line continuation) but probably has following whitespace characters.

Comment: I saved a `.txt` file with the contents: `print("Opened file!")` as a `.py` file.

Comment: Just to make sure: If you run `python` in the command line, do you get the Python interpreter?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/faddfaa002b775379dad38830b55f8a8

Comment: Why don't you create a new `.py` file, `Don't do the renaming thing of txt to py`, paste your code and see what you get!

Comment: The error `File "<stdin>", line 1` looks strange. It should be something like `File "test.py", line 1`. Please just call `python` without additional parameters. Do you get the Python interpreter?

Comment: I tried making a new file like @DeveshKumarSingh suggested. [Here's](http://prntscr.com/nm24he) what it looks like in my Python folder. I also tried changing the code in my command line to `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>python testFile` and `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>python testFile.py`, but I get the same error

Comment: You are trying to run a text document as a python file? It isn't supposed to work like that! Please open a editor like notepad, type your code it and `save` the file with `.py` extension and then run it!

Comment: That was a typo. It still outputted the same error as before, though

Comment: You get the same error with the non-existing file `testFile.py`? Seems as if `python` is not the Python executable but a script with the same name.

Comment: I just downloaded Python 3.7, and I'm opening the executable, not a pre-created script

Comment: But how do you know that? Please call `python.exe test.py`.

Comment: What do you mean call it? http://prntscr.com/nm27sg

Comment: Same as before. Until now you entered `python test.py`. Replace that with `python.exe test.py`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nm291f

Comment: OK, I've got no more ideas what might happen here.

Comment: This is a command to be typed into *your operating system's terminal prompt* in order to run Python, __NOT__ into an already running Python interpreter!  Furthermore, the "C:\Users\Your Name>" part is an example of the prompt where you'd be typing this, NOT something you'd type yourself.

Comment: So what do I do instead @jasonharper?

Comment: You need to just type `python test.py` at the command line judging by what you inputed in the last screenshot

Comment: @ChrisLallo, jasonharper is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Type `python test.py` into the shell directly, not into the python interpreter. The `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>` has backslashes in it, which cause this error as they make python expect the line to end.

Comment: I restarted my Python command line to make sure there was no existing code causing issues, and I copied and pasted the line that I put in my question (`C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>python test.py`). I know there's no whitespace, because I typed it again. What do you mean the IDLE?

Comment: Wait, are you typing `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Python>python test.py` into the python interpreter or into the command line? If into the interpreter, then yes, this sentence has backslashes and will give this error.